# How to make a line with border in horizontal, vertical and line crossing both

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Thats what i have to do only using HTML,CSS,JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6XDu.png)

[Thats what i did so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqhAN.png)

I trying to make this weather in the bottom with tr/td and some svg icons but i not going anywhere,i also tried something like a padding plus border radius and a background color but is not working, i only alowed to use HTML,CSS e JS (can't use bootstrap,jquery,angular, or any other API/Framework) maybe this is easy but i'm not a experienced front-end dev.

```
.white{
    background: #979797;
    border-radius: 20%;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From your **highlighted area** what I can presume is that you are looking for a dashed line and on top of that a solid thicker line. If my assumption is correct then I think the following css snippet can help you. It is just a rough sketch:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
div:before {
  border-bottom: 2px dashed red;
  width: 100%;
}
div:after {
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
```

Here I have targeted a div (you can add a class or target any other elements). Then in the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements I have added the styles to create two lines(dashed and solid)